# SQL/Impala Breaking the nested query into a more readable format

Tags: python, sql, impala

I have the following work python code to do impala connection/query:

---

```
import pandas as pd


query = 'select my_c_instance_id, count(my_c_instance_id) as my_ins_id_count from ' + \
         '(select * from my_table where my_c_id like "%small%") as small_table' + \
         ' group by(my_c_instance_id)'
cursor = impala_con.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE my_db')
cursor.execute(query)
df_result = as_pandas(cursor)
df_result
```

---

The codes work fine, but I am wondering if it is possible to break it into two more readable pieces, something like:

```
small_table = 'select * from my_table where my_c_id like "%small%"'

query = 'select my_c_instance_id, count(my_c_instance_id) as my_ins_id_count from small_table group by(my_c_instance_id)'

cursor = impala_con.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE my_db')
cursor.execute(query)
df_result = as_pandas(cursor)
df_result
```

If possible, how do I make the above idea actually work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, there's no need for the subquery at all, just move the `where` criteria to the main query:

```
select my_c_instance_id, count(my_c_instance_id) as my_ins_id_count 
from my_table 
where my_c_id like '%small%'
group by my_c_instance_id
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! But just for example purpose, is two separated queries possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame -- you could technically write a separate query using a  `common table expression`, but I'm not sure why that would be helpful.  In your above example, those 2 "queries" are just strings so you could keep them separated and concatonate the strings together before executing them.

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to make the first query to make the table_1, then make the second query on table_2? Is it the common table expression? how does it work exactly? Thanks!